# expected 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef but found 0xdeadbeebdeadbeef

Tags: macos, boot

I got this error during boot on my 2011 MacBook Pro. I'm not sure if a bit is flipped. I looked at the binary and it looks like a bit was flipped. 0xf = 1111 0xb = 1011 so it looks like a bit may have been flipped is there a way to tell if there is a faulty error in a registry or if this is just an error that occurred due to some anomaly?

```
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff8007b242ab): "a freed zone element has been 
modified in zone kalloc.64: expected 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef but found 
0xdeadbeebdeadbeef, bits changed 0x400000000, at offset 40 of 64 in element  
0xffffff801c4c1500, cookies 0x3f0011860f755f98 
0x535218f1d4d553f"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-
3248.30.4/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:503

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame
```